# get array result with wsdl and complexType

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

I need to send a date and get an array of records obtained response. My question is how should I define the complex type in WSDL.

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045847/array-response-in-wsdl-soap-php) shows me one way does not work me

Answer (score 0):

My Web Service:

```
    function pagos($fecha){
    require_once "include/conexion.php";
    $result = sqlsrv_query2("
consulta");
    $datos = array();
    $c=0;
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
        for($i = 0; $i<6;$i++){
            $datos[$c][$i]=$row[$i];
        }
        $c++;
    }
    return $datos; //devuelvo un array multidimensional de 6 columnas
}

$server->AddFunction("pagos");
$server->handle();`enter code here
```

My WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions name="AritmeticaServicio"
    targetNamespace="urn:Aritmetica"
     xmlns:tns="urn:Aritmetica"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
     xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:Aritmetica">
      <xsd:complexType name="resultArray">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
            <attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType"
                       wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[][]"/>
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <message name="AritmeticaPeticion">
    <part name="operando1" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>

  <message name="AritmeticaRespuesta">
    <part name="respuesta" type="xsd:resultArray" />
  </message>

  <portType name="AritmeticaPort">
    <operation name="pagos">
      <input message="tns:AritmeticaPeticion" />
      <output message="tns:AritmeticaRespuesta" />
    </operation>
  </portType>

  <binding name="AritmeticaBinding" type="tns:AritmeticaPort">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="pagos">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Aritmetica#pagos" />
        <input>
          <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Aritmetica"
                     encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </input>
        <output>
          <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:Aritmetica"
                     encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>  
    <service name="AritmeticaServicio">
      <port name="AritmeticaPort" binding="tns:AritmeticaBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/proyecto/server.php" />
      </port>
    </service>    
</definitions>
```

I call in client

```
try{
 $clienteSOAP = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8080/proyecto/aritmetica.wsdl');
 $resultado_pago = $clienteSOAP->pagos('2014-06-30');
  echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($resultado_pago);

} catch(SoapFault $e){
echo '<pre>';
 print_r($e);
}
```

I no data returns an object